# CSS Border redundancy removal

Tags: css

I often find myself into this:

```
.class {
   border-top:1px dashed #0000000;
   border-bottom:1px dashed #0000000;
}
```

Is there a way to one-line that?

I tried this but doenst' work:

```
.class {
   border:1px 0 dashed #0000000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use properties for every "side" (top, right, bottom, left) for each single border property, in your case:

```
.class{
border-color: #000;
border-width: 1px 0;
border-style: dashed;

}
```

Note that you can specify every property for every side, for example:

```
.class{
border-color: #000 green blue yellow;
border-width: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
border-style: dashed solid dotted solid;

}
```

Comment: it is supposed to show that you can set every border property for every side of a box. The first example does not really show that

Answer (score 4):

No but you could make it simpler to maintain by using:

```
.my_class {
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}
```

That what you only need to change one line.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's no one-liner for that in pure CSS - you can use the  `border` shorthand only for all four sides at once.